# How to make `cv2.imshow()` window fit in the screen?

Tags: python, macos, opencv

For a very large image, `cv2.imshow()`makes the window larger than the screen. Is there a way to make it fit to the screen? I use Mac OS X. Thanks.

Comment: resize the image

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this will do the trick.

```
cv2.namedWindow('window', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('window', img)
```